# Combine Two Queries (Rank and Cumulative) used in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ranking, cumulative-sum

I have two queries:

1. Will sum daily readings on a time zero basis (normalized or ranked) - takes time out of the equation.
2. Will CUM readings through time, a running total.

I'd like to combine the two so that I can have a cumulative output of normalized/time-zero/ranked data.

Here is the time zero query (1):

```
SELECT Sum([_Group_Norm_Query].Sales) AS SumOfSales 
FROM (SELECT 
tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY, 
tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate,
tblTempGroupNorm.Sales, 
(SELECT COUNT(Table1A.ReadingDate) FROM tblTempGroupNorm AS Table1A 
 WHERE Table1A.ReadingDate<=tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate 
 AND Table1A.Prop_KEY = tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY) AS TimeDay 
FROM
tblProperties INNER JOIN tblTempGroupNorm ON tblProperties.WH_IDX = tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY 
WHERE (((tblProperties.GROUP)='MY GROUP') AND ((tblProperties.AREA)='MY AREA')) ORDER BY
tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate) AS [_Group_Norm_Query] 
GROUP BY[_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay;
```

And here is the running total query (2):

```
SELECT Sum(a2.Sales) AS SumOfSales
FROM tblTempGroupNorm AS a1 INNER JOIN (tblTempGroupNorm AS a2 INNER JOIN tblProperties ON a2.Prop_KEY = tblProperties.WH_IDX) ON a1.Prop_KEY = tblProperties.WH_IDX
WHERE (((a2.ReadingDate)<=[a1].[ReadingDate]) AND (([tblProperties].[GROUP])='MY GROUP') AND (([tblProperties].[AREA])='MY AREA'))
GROUP BY a1.ReadingDate
ORDER BY a1.ReadingDate;
```

Any thoughts on combining the two? I'm avoiding the use of DSUM() in the running total, and cannot use it in the final combined query either. Thanks

**Edit:** Following feedback, here is my attempt to combine them. I get an error:

> query does not include specified expression `'COUNT(a2.ReadingDate) = [_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay` as part of an aggregate function.

If I remove the very last line `(GOUP BY [_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay;` The error is suppressed, but the query never completes - it locks up.

```
SELECT Sum([_Group_Norm_Query].Sales) AS SumOfSales, Sum(RunTotal.SumOfSales) AS MY_RUNNING_TOTAL 

SELECT Sum(a2.Sales) AS SumOfSales
FROM tblTempGroupNorm AS a1 INNER JOIN (tblTempGroupNorm AS a2 INNER JOIN tblProperties ON a2.Prop_KEY = tblProperties.WH_IDX) ON a1.Prop_KEY = tblProperties.WH_IDX
WHERE (((a2.ReadingDate)<=[a1].[ReadingDate]) AND (([tblProperties].[GROUP])='MY GROUP') AND (([tblProperties].[AREA])='MY AREA'))
GROUP BY a1.ReadingDate
HAVING COUNT(a2.ReadingDate) = [_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay
ORDER BY a1.ReadingDate) AS RunTotal

FROM (SELECT 
tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY, 
tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate,
tblTempGroupNorm.Sales, 
    (SELECT COUNT(Table1A.ReadingDate) FROM tblTempGroupNorm AS Table1A 
    WHERE Table1A.ReadingDate<=tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate 
     AND Table1A.Prop_KEY = tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY) AS TimeDay 
FROM
tblProperties INNER JOIN tblTempGroupNorm ON tblProperties.WH_IDX = tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY 
WHERE (((tblProperties.GROUP)='MY GROUP') AND ((tblProperties.AREA)='MY AREA')) ORDER BY
tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate) AS [_Group_Norm_Query]

GROUP BY[_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay;
```

Comment: `DSum` is essentially a subquery. Why not add the second query into first as a second subquery after the TimeDay one?

Comment: The first totals sales for all properties matching the where clause on a normalized basis.
the second will create a running total through time (data not normalized). 
So i need to have a running total of the first query results.  I'm not certain that adding the second query into the first accomplishes that.

Comment: I just tried doing this, and I got an alert I haven't seen before: "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."

Comment: You must relate the subquery to outer query row by row. Try adding this `HAVING` clause after `GROUP BY` in second query which I suggest as subquery in first: `HAVING COUNT(a2.ReadingDate) = [_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay`

Comment: I tried to add the running total query as a sub-query to the first. The SQL was added after "AS _Group_Norm_Query", and I added the HAVING condition you suggested. However, the query does not recognize [_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay used in the HAVING statement, a prompt is presented as if the field is a parameter. Maybe I'm adding to the wrong spot in the query?

Comment: Try adding the subquery with `HAVING` clause after the very first line of outer main query: `SELECT Sum([_Group_Norm_Query].Sales) AS SumOfSales`. Just like the very last `GROUP BY` line which is part of outer main query, TimeDay should be recognized.

Comment: I made the change.     TimeDay is now recognized, but having a grouping issue. I feel like we're close. See edit in post for current query mash-up status.

Answer (score 0):

For your `HAVING` clause error, try fixing the punctuation around your subquery - comma and parenthesis:

```
SELECT [_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay, Sum([_Group_Norm_Query].Sales) AS SumOfSales, 
Sum(RunTotal.SumOfSales) AS MY_RUNNING_TOTAL, 

  (SELECT Sum(a2.Sales) AS SumOfSales
   FROM tblTempGroupNorm AS a1 
   INNER JOIN (tblTempGroupNorm AS a2 
   INNER JOIN tblProperties ON a2.Prop_KEY = tblProperties.WH_IDX) 
          ON a1.Prop_KEY = tblProperties.WH_IDX
   WHERE (((a2.ReadingDate)<=[a1].[ReadingDate]) 
          AND (([tblProperties].[GROUP])='MY GROUP') 
          AND (([tblProperties].[AREA])='MY AREA'))
   GROUP BY a1.ReadingDate
   HAVING COUNT(a2.ReadingDate) = [_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay
   ORDER BY a1.ReadingDate) AS RunTotal

FROM 
    (SELECT tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY, tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate,
        tblTempGroupNorm.Sales, 
    (SELECT COUNT(Table1A.ReadingDate) FROM tblTempGroupNorm AS Table1A 
     WHERE Table1A.ReadingDate<=tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate 
        AND Table1A.Prop_KEY = tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY) AS TimeDay 
     FROM tblProperties 
     INNER JOIN tblTempGroupNorm ON tblProperties.WH_IDX = tblTempGroupNorm.Prop_KEY 
     WHERE (((tblProperties.GROUP)='MY GROUP') AND ((tblProperties.AREA)='MY AREA')) 
     ORDER BY tblTempGroupNorm.ReadingDate) AS [_Group_Norm_Query]

GROUP BY[_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay;
```

Comment: _Query does not include specified expression    `COUNT(a2.ReadingDate)=[_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay`    as part of an aggregate function._

Comment: See my edit. Try adding `[_Group_Norm_Query].TimeDay` in the `SELECT` line. The `HAVING` clause may not be seeing the field from outer query.

Comment: Test out the HAVING clause with any number like 5 to see if the query runs: `HAVING COUNT(a2.ReadingDate) = 5`

Comment: If I make the change as you suggested, the query runs. I get time day counting from 1 to correct # of rows. SumOfSales appears correct as well. Then I get 2 other columns: MY_RUNNING_TOTAL and RunTotal. MY_RUNNING_TOTAL returns values that are the same for multiple rows, then change to a smaller number, and the pattern repeats. I get the feeling it's returning the sum of Sales for all properties with <= that number of days. Then when the property count drops, the sum value changes.R unTotal returns the same number for all rows, a very small number relative to the output maybe the sum of 5 days